# Split string into words and assign to new columns

Tags: r, split

I have speaking `Turn`s of different lengths. I want to break the `Turn`s into individual words and assign each word to a new column depending on the word's position in the utterance:

```
test <- data.frame(
  Speaker = c("PS1G3","PS1G2","PS1G3","PS1G2"),
  N_words = c(2,3,4,1),
  Turn = c("can you","what 's the","are you going up","what"),
  c5 = c("VM0 PNP","DTQ VBZ AT0","VBB PNP VVG AVP","DTQ"))
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
test
  Speaker N_words             Turn              c5   w1   w2    w3   w4
1   PS1G3       2          can you         VM0 PNP  can  you  <NA> <NA>
2   PS1G2       3      what 's the     DTQ VBZ AT0 what   's   the <NA>
3   PS1G3       4 are you going up VBB PNP VVG AVP  are  you going   up
4   PS1G2       1             what             DTQ what <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

I know how to split the `Turn`s into individual words but am stuck there:

```
lapply(test$Turn, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `tidyverse` approach may also help

```r
test <- data.frame(
  Speaker = c("PS1G3","PS1G2","PS1G3","PS1G2"),
  N_words = c(2,3,4,1),
  Turn = c("can you","what 's the","are you going up","what"),
  c5 = c("VM0 PNP","DTQ VBZ AT0","VBB PNP VVG AVP","DTQ"))

library(tidyverse)

test %>% separate(Turn, into = paste0('w', seq_len(1 + max(str_count(test$Turn, ' ')))), fill = 'right', remove = F, sep = ' ')
#>   Speaker N_words             Turn   w1   w2    w3   w4              c5
#> 1   PS1G3       2          can you  can  you  <NA> <NA>         VM0 PNP
#> 2   PS1G2       3      what 's the what   's   the <NA>     DTQ VBZ AT0
#> 3   PS1G3       4 are you going up  are  you going   up VBB PNP VVG AVP
#> 4   PS1G2       1             what what <NA>  <NA> <NA>             DTQ
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great. But I'd like to keep the column `Turn`. How can that be done?

Comment: Just one more thing: why are you using `str_count(test$Turn, ' ')`and not just `str_count(Turn, ' ')`?

Comment: It is because, I would like to be `test$Turn` to be hard-coded, though in the present example it doesn't matter.

Comment: See sometimes, the data is broken into groups before `separating` in these strings.  In that case, the `max(str_count(test, ' '))` will be different for each group.  therefore, it is always safer to hard-code the dataframe name here.  Then the `group_by` won't hamper your results.  I think I am pretty much clear this time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `lapply` to split the string. The splitted string is extended to the longest length using `[` in `sapply`. The result is `cbind` to *test*.

```
tt <- strsplit(test$Turn, "\\s")
cbind(test, t(sapply(tt, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(tt))))))
#  Speaker N_words             Turn              c5    1    2     3    4
#1   PS1G3       2          can you         VM0 PNP  can  you  <NA> <NA>
#2   PS1G2       3      what 's the     DTQ VBZ AT0 what   's   the <NA>
#3   PS1G3       4 are you going up VBB PNP VVG AVP  are  you going   up
#4   PS1G2       1             what             DTQ what <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` :

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(test, 'Turn', sep = "\\s", fixed = FALSE, stripWhite = FALSE)

#   Speaker N_words              c5 Turn_1 Turn_2 Turn_3 Turn_4
#1:   PS1G3       2         VM0 PNP    can    you   <NA>   <NA>
#2:   PS1G2       3     DTQ VBZ AT0   what     's    the   <NA>
#3:   PS1G3       4 VBB PNP VVG AVP    are    you  going     up
#4:   PS1G2       1             DTQ   what   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `read.table` from `base R`

```
cbind(test, read.table(text = test$Turn, 
       header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, quote = "",  na.strings = ""))
```

-output

```
#  Speaker N_words             Turn              c5   V1   V2    V3   V4
#1   PS1G3       2          can you         VM0 PNP  can  you  <NA> <NA>
#2   PS1G2       3      what 's the     DTQ VBZ AT0 what   's   the <NA>
#3   PS1G3       4 are you going up VBB PNP VVG AVP  are  you going   up
#4   PS1G2       1             what             DTQ what <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```